# Text to a list python

Tags: list, python-3.x, sudoku

i'm trying to read a sudoku and put it on a list,
i have something like this.

`0,0,0,0,7,0,2,6,0
0,6,0,8,0,2,0,3,5
0,0,5,3,0,0,0,7,0
0,7,6,0,0,0,0,2,0
0,8,9,6,0,0,0,4,0
0,3,0,5,4,0,0,8,0
0,0,0,2,8,0,0,0,0
0,2,0,4,0,0,0,0,3
0,0,8,7,0,3,6,0,0`

i need convert it on a list like this

```
board = [['0', '0', '0', '0', '7', '0', '2', '6', '0'], ['0', '6', '0', '8',     
'0', '2', '0', '3', '5'], ['0', '0', '5', '3', '0', '0', '0', '7', '0'], 
['0','7', '6', '0', '0', '0', '0', '2', '0'], ['0', '8', '9', '6', '0', 
'0', '0','4', '0'], ['0', '3', '0', '5', '4', '0', '0', '8', '0'], 
['0', '0', '0', '2','8', '0', '0', '0', '0'], ['0', '2', '0', '4', '0', 
'0', '0', '0', '3'], ['0','0', '8', '7', '0', '3', '6', '0', '0']]
```

I'm using this code but have a problem

`tablero = open('sd1.txt', 'r')
board = [line.split(',') for line in tablero.readlines()]`

The result is:

```
board = [['0', '0', '0', '0', '7', '0', '2', '6', '0\n'], ['0', '6', '0', 
'8', '0', '2', '0', '3', '5\n'], ['0', '0', '5', '3', '0', '0', '0', '7', 
'0\n'], ['0', '7', '6', '0', '0', '0', '0', '2', '0\n'], ['0', '8', '9', 
'6', '0', '0', '0', '4', '0\n'], ['0', '3', '0', '5', '4', '0', '0', '8', 
'0\n'], ['0', '0', '0', '2', '8', '0', '0', '0', '0\n'], ['0', '2', '0', 
'4', '0', '0', '0', '0', '3\n'], ['0', '0', '8', '7', '0', '3', '6', '0', 
'0\n']]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.strip()` to remove leading and trailing whitespace (including the trailing newline that is causing your trouble):

```
board = [line.strip().split(',') for line in tablero.readlines()]
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to remove the '\n' by using `line.strip('\n\r')`.

Or you could also use `line[:-1].split(',')`, which also removes the last newline character.

Answer (score 0):

in case you have the problem at the end of line, you can do a right strip  as same Jez but only on the right part..basically..it does the same but only the right of the string .

```
board = [line.rstrip().split(',') for line in tablero.readlines()]
```